# What is the perineal sponge (female anatomy)?

Tags: anatomy, gynecology, embryology

In particular, what embryonic structure does [the perineal sponge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perineal_sponge) develop from and what male structure is it homologous to?

Oh, and does it even exist at all? Because the data/mentions in the literature are kinda scarce.

I did find:

- this website: https://intimateartscenter.com/the-missing-female-pleasure-parts/ (which is not a peer-reviewed article)
- this image (which might originally come from some anatomy publication, but my attempt to trace it back to the source wasn't successful):

[image: female anayomy illustration]

- the book "A New view of a woman's body" (1981), which I believe introduced this term in the first place. It states the existence of this structure, provides some drawings, and claims that the perineal sponge is part of the clitoral complex and essentially is a posterior extension of the vestibule bulbs. However, the book doesn't provide any anatomical references.
- another website, which claims that the perineal sponge "the wall between the vagina and the rectum": https://www.naturalcycles.com/cyclematters/the-female-pleasure-anatomy-explained

No reputable anatomy atlas or book I've checked mentions this structure (Ellis et al, Cianca & Patel, Moller & Reif, Saladin etc), and no peer-reviewed anatomy article mentions it. The structure is mostly mentioned in books and articles on sexual psychology (often passingly), books on how to reach orgasm etc.

Also, I have found a dissection anatomy video where I noticed something that looks like a cavernous structure exactly where one would expect to find the perineal sponge. However, I'm not an expert in dissections, and the narrator in the video doesn't acknowledge this structure in any way. So what it really is remains to be confirmed. Here's the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1ezGxWlcHU

And here's a screenshot where I pinpoint the structure:
[image]

Comment: If you enter the term into google you get a lengthy list of hits from reputable sources that answer your question, so I don't understand why you're claiming you can't find sources and especially why you're questioning its existence.

Comment: @CareyGregory, because the only source that specifically mentions this sponge is Wikipedia and some non-peer-reviewed "how to please a lady" articles; because all anatomy books and atlases I've managed to get my hands on don't mention it at all; and because the search on scholar.google returns nothing on the topic but a few passing mentions in some non-anatomical articles. Trust me, I have googled and looked. Perhaps you are confusing it with "perineal body" (whose existence is not up to question indeed).

Comment: @JiminyCricket, well, I've noticed that general anatomy questions are allowed on the site, so I hope the question isn't out of place.

Comment: Well, nothing official indeed, but the info [here](https://www.naturalcycles.com/cyclematters/the-female-pleasure-anatomy-explained) appears to be correct, there's a part about perineal sponge and its function. You probably saw this too while searching, hence I didn't post this as answer. If you won't get any better answer in few days, you can probably post this as self answer, i.e. link to that site and quote the relevant part.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard, thanks. I've updated the question details for now. At this point I'm quite far from understanding what this structure really is, which means I probably shouldn't post a self-asnwer yet.